# How can I inject a native dll from C# application using SetWindowHookEx (and is it safer than injecting with CreateRemoteThread)

Tags: c#, c, winapi, hook, code-injection

First of all, I don't want to monitor the keyboard or mouse, I only want to load my dll into the other process's address space. I'm currently doing this with external unmanaged dll which does WriteProcessMemory, VirtualAllocEx and then CreateRemoteThread. But this is usually detected as a virus. Will the SetWindowsHookEx be safer for the antiviruses? And if so, how to use it from C# - what WH_* value should I use?

EDIT:
My DLL is unmanaged (written in C)

Comment: So you want an example of use of SetWindowsHookEx from C or what? The type of hook is based on when you want to be called for that hook.

Comment: The reason why your anti-virus is flagging this as suspicious is because injecting code into other processes is generally speaking a Bad Thing (TM). If you manage to achieve this in some other way than just WPM/VAX/CRT you'll still be flagged by an anti-virus because they're not objecting to CRT - they're objecting to the fact that you're trying to inject code into another process.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code would be analogous to your native code, using PInvoke to call the Virtual* functions.

It is unlikely it wouldn't be detected by an antivirus program, if your native code is.

It sounds like the antivirus is the problem, and not your code.

Although you might be able to mitigate it somewhat, depending on the antivirus vendor they may allow this sort of hooking (for computer based training...) without issue if your app is digitally signed and the cert chains up to a trusted root.